# Is there a geometric analogy for separable space?

Tags: functional-analysis

Is there a geometric analogy that could help me with understanding the concept of separable space?

Comment: Perhaps imagine your space as actual space, and imagine a sequence of points, which can be, one by one, put into the space such that every point of the space is eventually very close to a point of the sequence, given enough points have been put into the space.

Answer (score 0):

A separable space is which has a countable dense subset. $\mathbb{R}$ is simple geometric example having this property that every neighborhood of an element of $\mathbb{R}$ has nonempty intersection with $\mathbb{Q}.$ Every separable space must have this property.

Comment: I was hoping something that could help to visualize that "separable" in the definition. I don't see the distinction with dense and separable with your example.

Comment: If $A\subset B$ and $\bar{A}=B$ the A is a dense subset of $B$. Also If a space have a dense subset or subspace then it is called separable.

Comment: Probably i'm missing something... so are they the same thing?

Comment: The example presented above with me is quite geometric. Be careful every neighborhood of any rational number has nonempty intersection with $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: But what's the difference with the definition of dense subset? Is it possible to find a dense subset of a set which isn't separable (even if we are speaking of vector space... i think i made my point) and/or a separable set which isn't dense?